# GXT 3 Grid height and scroll

Tags: gwt, gxt

My environment is: GWTP 0.7, GWT 2.4.0, GXT 3.0.1. This question is somehow related to [GXT 3 grid scrolling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050354/gxt-3-grid-scrolling-issue) but with the exception that the solution there does not work for me.

My case:

```
public abstract class AbstractGridView extends ViewImpl implements AbstractGridPresenter.MyView {

    protected final VerticalLayoutContainer cont = new VerticalLayoutContainer();

    protected final VerticalLayoutData toolBarData = new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1);
    protected final VerticalLayoutData contentData = new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1); //grid's layout config

    protected final ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
    protected final TextButton addItemButton = new TextButton(ADDBUTTON_TEXT);

    @Inject
    protected AbstractGridView() {
        toolBar.add(addItemButton);
        cont.add(toolBar, toolBarData);
    }

    public Widget asWidget() {
        return cont;
    }
}    
public class DepartmentsView extends AbstractGridView implements DepartmentsPresenter.MyView {
    private final Grid<Department> grid;
    private final ColumnModel<Department> model;
    private final List<ColumnConfig<Department, ?>> config = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig<Department,?>>();
    private final ListStore<Department> store = new ListStore<Department>(PROPS.key());
    @Inject
    public DepartmentsView() {
        super();
        config.add(new ColumnConfig<Department, Long>(PROPS.id()));
        config.get(config.size() - 1).setHeader(IDCOLUMN_HEADER);
        config.add(new ColumnConfig<Department, String>(PROPS.name()));
        config.get(config.size() - 1).setHeader(NAMECOLUMN_HEADER);
        config.add(new ColumnConfig<Department, String>(companyNameProvider));
        config.get(config.size() - 1).setHeader(COMPANYCOLUMN_HEADER);

        model = new ColumnModel<Department>(config);

        grid = new Grid<Department>(store, model);
        grid.getView().setAutoFill(true);

        filters.initPlugin(grid);
        filters.setLocal(true);
        filters.addFilter(idFilter);
        filters.addFilter(nameFilter);
        filters.addFilter(companyFilter);

        cont.add(grid);
    }
}
```

All these are injected into BorderLayoutContainer in BaseView:

```
public class BaseView extends ViewImpl implements BasePresenter.MyView {
    private final Viewport viewPort = new Viewport();

    private final BorderLayoutContainer borderContainer = new BorderLayoutContainer();

    private final ContentPanel west = new ContentPanel();
    private final ContentPanel north = new ContentPanel();
    private final ContentPanel center = new ContentPanel();
    private final BorderLayoutData westData = new BorderLayoutData(200);
    private final BorderLayoutData northData = new BorderLayoutData();
    private final BorderLayoutData centerData = new BorderLayoutData();
    @Inject
    public BaseView() {
        borderContainer.setBorders(true);
        west.setResize(true);
        center.setResize(false);
        center.setHeight("auto");
        north.setResize(false);
        westData.setCollapsible(false);
        westData.setCollapseMini(false);
        westData.setMargins(new Margins(5, 5, 5, 5));
        northData.setCollapsible(false);
        northData.setMargins(new Margins(5));
        northData.setSize(57);
        centerData.setCollapsible(false);
        centerData.setMargins(new Margins(5));
        borderContainer.setWestWidget(west, westData);
        borderContainer.setCenterWidget(center, centerData);
        borderContainer.setNorthWidget(north, northData);
        viewPort.add(borderContainer);
    }

    public Widget asWidget() {
        return viewPort;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInSlot(Object slot, Widget content) {
        setMainContent(content);
    }

    private void setMainContent(Widget content) {
        center.clear();
        if (content != null) {
            center.setWidget(content);
        }
    }
}
```

So, if I do not attach contentData when adding my grid to VerticalLayoutContainer (cont) it renders equally to as VerticalLayoutData(1, -1) which is: grid's height is not computed at all and it's content flows under the bottom of the page with no scrollbar to get to any row lower the bottom page border. If I set VerticalLayoutData (1, 1) as in the link at the beginning of my question I can only see grid's header and grid's content's height is computed to 0px (though it's present in the page's DOM). And only if I set height manually, for example setHeight(300) grid's height sets that quantity of pixels and vertical scrollbar is shown to get to any row in the grid's store, though one can easily understand manually setting grid's height is not of any reason solution in case of Viewport managed application window.

What have I missed in widgets config or is this a bug with any reasonable workaround for it?

Comment: You seem to be missing bits of the example - `contentData` is never actually used. If it is used for a `Grid` though, it must not have a -1 value.

Comment: I actually tried to use id, not to use it and use contentData instanced as VerticalLayoutData(1, 1); But I've found error myself already: it's `center.setResize(false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the layout problem:

```
center.setResize(false); // BaseView's constructor
```

That made BorderLayoutContainer's ContentPanel not to resize child widget (VerticalLayoutContainer) to fit.